# Is Clearbox deprecated?

Tags: javascript, html, deprecated

I would like to use the javascript library clearbox for a new site, but I can't find the officiel web site. The original url (http://www.clearbox.hu/index_en.html) is not working anymore. 
What happened to the developer ? What can I use with the same gallery fonctionnalites ?

EDIT : New site : http://kreaturamedia.com/clearbox/index_en.html

Comment: I don't think "deprecated" means what you think it means. Are you asking whether it's been abandoned? Or something different?

Comment: Also, if you want to know "What happened to the developer?": http://clearbox.hu redirects to http://kreaturamedia.com, which has a nice ["contact"](http://kreaturamedia.com/contact/) link. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look on [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

Very good solution for my opinion. Easy to use and works nice.

If talking about lightbox, I use [that](http://visuallightbox.com/) for one time. It's also very nice.